# XML Parsing error when accessing Yii generated WSDL

Tags: php, xml, web-services, wsdl, yii

I'm trying to create a simple example web service with yii.  I followed these [directions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.webservice), but I'm getting an error when I try to visit the WSDL to view what yii generated.  Visiting the WSDL at http://localhost/mywebapp/index.php/L1Folio/folio

**Error:**

```
XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: http://localhost/paperless_admin/index.php/L1Folio/folio
Line Number 4, Column 1:
<table class="yiiLog" width="100%" cellpadding="2" style="border-spacing:1px;font:11px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;color:#666666;">
^
```

**Code:**

L1FolioController.php:

```
<?php

class L1FolioController extends CController
{
    public function actions()
    {
        return array(
            'folio'=>array(
                'class'=>'CWebServiceAction',
            ),
        );
    }
    /**
     * @param  string the folio
     * @return string the statement
     * @soap
     */
    public function sendFolio($folio)
    {
      return 'it works';
    }

}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.  The logging options conflict with the WSDL XML.  Your main.php config should look like this in the log section:

```
'log'=>array(
                        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
                        'routes'=>array(
                                array(
                                        'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                                        'levels'=>'error, warning',                                        
                                ),
                                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages                            
                                /*array(
                                        'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                                ),*/

                        ),
                ),
```